# List of Lists contains another list in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know the title is a little bit confusing, but let me try make it more easy to understand.

I Have two objects:

```
List<Professional>

List<Skills>
```

But each `Professional` has a

```
List<Skills>
```

so I got something like this:

```
var allProfessionals = getAllProfessionals();
var jobOffertSkills = jobOffert.Skills;
```

So my question is, using linq, how can I get the Professionals that contains all skills contained in jobOffertSkills?

Answer (score 7):

```
var machingProfessionals = allProfessionals.Where(p => jobOffertSkilss.All(sk => p.Skills.Contains(sk)));
```

Comment: It doesn't works :( - I think because I have to compare the `professional.Skills.All(jobOffertSkills)` - I still got a empty result list, but I must to get at least one record.

Comment: @guisantogui How does it not work? Does it not compile, or does it return an unexpected result?

Comment: I got an unexpected result >> "I still got a empty result list, but I must to get at least one record", sorry if I didn't make me understandable.

Comment: @guisantogui - Do you have a simple automated test for this? You should create a minimal set of sample data to test this against. Then, update your question to show some test data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class `Skill` implements the `IEquatable<Skill>` then you can try this :

```
var professionals = getAllProfessionals();
var requiredSkills = jobOffert.Skills;

var qualifiedProfessionals = professionals.Where(
    p => !requiredSkills.Except(p.Skills).Any());
```